# How to select checkbox of all rows in jqgrid based on a click of a button?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, jqgrid

I have a JQGrid(jqgrid-3.6.4) in my web page. The first column of that is check box. Based on click of a button, I need to check the check box of all rows of JQGrid. I cannot use "multiselect=true" because I need to have additional functionality on checking a check box. So far I have this to iterate through all rows of jqgrid and retrieve column values and set the checkbox in the first column:

```
var rows = jQuery("#demoJQGrid").getDataIDs();
for(var a=0;a<=rows.length;a++)
{
    var row=jQuery("#demoJQGrid").getRowData(rows[a]);          

    row.columnOneCheckBox.attr('checked',true);   

    jQuery("#demoJQGrid").setRowData(rows[a],row );

}
```

This does not check the checkboxes when I click a button. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
var cbs = $("tr.jqgrow > td > input.mycboxclass", jQuery("#demoJQGrid")[0]);
cbs.attr("checked", true)
```

where 'mycboxclass' is a class added to your checkbox elements.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this attr try the below code

```
row.CB = "True"; // CB your Column Name and set true to check the checkbox
$('#demoJQGrid').setRowData(rows[a], row);
```